# how can I fix my JList? It's not appearing

Tags: java

The list isn't showing on the panel, however when I replace `panel2.add(new JScrollPane(insuranceplan))` with `panel2.add(insuranceplan)`, I can see the list but I can only select 1 item.

lab9 is  a JLable/ insuranceplan is a Jlist / InsurancePlan is a string [];

```
     lab9= new JLabel ("Insurance Plan");lab9.setBounds(10,150,165,25);
     insuranceplan = new JList(InsurancePlan) ;                    
     insuranceplan.setVisibleRowCount(3);
     insuranceplan.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
     insuranceplan.setBounds(150,150,200,25);
     panel2.add(new JScrollPane(insuranceplan));   panel2.add(lab9);
```

Comment: please provide more code and a screenshot of what your program looks like currently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Panel 2 seems to used absolute layout (based on your code).

You provide bounds for `lab9` and `insuranceplan`, but not for JScrollPane.